# What's wrong with my program (getch function)?

Tags: c

I'm learning C programming language and while I was doing some practicing I faced an error about my `getch()` function!

Here's my code :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int size = 6;
    int markers[size];
    int counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++){
        scanf("%d",&markers[counter]);
    }

    for (counter=0; counter < size; counter++){
        printf("The element at %d is %d\n",counter,markers[counter]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I faced an error" This is as vague as it gets. Please specify what is the error, is it a compile error? Is it strange behavior... what?

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message.

Comment: put `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: There is an error "undefined reference to `getch'", so it is necessary to include proper header <conio.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getch()` is not an ANSI C function. You need to include the header file `<conio.h>` to use it. Or best of all, just use the ANSI conformant function `getchar()`.

Comment: It is also not an **ISO** C function. (ANSI-C, aka C89 is not C standard anway - since >25 years)

Comment: The ANSI standard is irrelevant, as there is an international standard available, which has been adopted by most (if not all) national institutes. And the version meant with this (C89) is not standard anymore. As C has evolved since then, your answer leaves open standard C now might include `getch`. As it has not, the correct answer would either be "`getch` is not a standard C function" or "... no C11 function". Because there is only one valid standard.

Comment: Where did you get the 25 year figure from? Besides, why would the committe all of a sudden decide to add `getch` when `getchar` already exists? @Olaf

Comment: I learned that long time ago at school: `2016 - 1989 > 25`. And the commitee did even more strange things in the past. But that is not the point.

Answer (score 0):

use `getchar()` from the standard libraries instead of `getch()`
If you want to  to use `getch()` include `#include <curses.h>` on unix or `#include <conio.h>` on windows.